# Fixed DIV won't scroll in mobile but will in minimized desktop view?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I'm using Bootstrap w/ Jansy Bootstrap.

I have a fixed div on desktop. When I shorten my desktop browser the scroll bar appears on the left sidebar and I can scroll down to see the content below the viewport.

When I view it on mobile though, there is no scroll action.

How can I have scroll-action on a desktop shortened to 320px wide but none on an iPhone?

My page is here: http://thebigcheezy.apps-1and1.com/home2

Comment: what mobile? Android? also what is a scroll action?

Comment: "Scroll-action" is just the ability to scroll up or down if the content is too big for the viewport. This problem is on both Android and Safari.

Comment: From what I can tell, the scrollbar only disappears when you have the menu open while the viewport is too small.  Is that what you're referring to?

Comment: I've added this css to make the scrollbar appear in the desktop view. When viewed on mobile however, the scrollbar is gone and I have no "scroll-action" :)

`
@media (max-width: 1000px) {
.navmenu-fixed-left, .navmenu-fixed-right, .navbar-offcanvas {

    top: 0;
    bottom:0;
    position:fixed;
    overflow-y:scroll;
    overflow-x:hidden;

}
}
`

Comment: I'm having a hard time duplicating your problem, the only time the "scroll action" doesn't work for me is if I start with my finger on the slideshow or when the menu is open.

Comment: Are you on an iPhone? Are you telling me the sidebar is scrolling or the content in the background is? Using an iPhone 4s I have no scrollbar but using my HTC One I don't need one so I understand it not being there.

Comment: It works fine on an iphone 4s, iphone mega, nexus 7 tablet and s5 phone.  Those are all my testing devices.  I can't replicate it.

Comment: Wow well thanks for the time. Here's a link of my issue. Maybe I should try it on a different iPhone.

https://youtu.be/SDcmL_nKbx4

Comment: I have tested this on the iPhone and it will not scroll. Did you actually test on the devices or was it a device emulator?